# Android connection from PHP (online database) to Android is not working

Tags: java, php, android, android-fragments, httprequest

I'm trying to retrieve a specific string on my site. `http://plpemag.byethost31.com/functions.php?action=printSpecificArticle&articleid=2` through android and display it on my textview. But when I run the program, the textView is still blank. What might be the problem for this?

**GetMethodEx.java**

```
package com.example.navigationdrawerexample;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class GetMethodEx {
    public String getInternetData() throws Exception{
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;

        try{
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI website = new URI("http://plpemag.byethost31.com/functions.php?action=printSpecificArticle&articleid=2");
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(website);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l = "";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((l = in.readLine()) !=null){
                sb.append(l+nl);
            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            return data;
        }finally{
            if (in != null){
                try{
                    in.close();
                    return data;
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CollegeBulletinListFragment.java**

```
package com.example.navigationdrawerexample;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CollegeBulletinListFragment extends Fragment{
    public CollegeBulletinListFragment(){
    }

    TextView kem;
    TextView tester;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_collegebulletinlist, container, false);
        kem = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.angkembular);
        tester = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tester);
        Bundle bun = getArguments();
        setTextAndColorsToHead(bun.getString("passingWord"));
        GetMethodEx gm = new GetMethodEx();
        String returned;
        try {
            returned = gm.getInternetData();
            tester.setText(returned);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    public void setTextAndColorsToHead(String arg){
        if (arg.equals("GN")){
            kem.setText("General News");
        } else if (arg.equals("CCS")){
            kem.setText("College of Computer Studies");
        } else if (arg.equals("COE")){
            kem.setText("College of Engineering");
        } else if (arg.equals("COED")){
            kem.setText("College of Education");
        } else if (arg.equals("CON")){
            kem.setText("College of Nursing");
        } else if (arg.equals("CBA")){
            kem.setText("College of Business and Accountancy");
        } else if (arg.equals("CAS")){
            kem.setText("College of Arts and Sciences");
        } else if (arg.equals("CIHM")){
            kem.setText("College of International and Hospitality Management");
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The link: http://plpemag.byethost31.com/functions.php?action=printSpecificArticle&articleid=2    gives a json format of the data fetched from the database. Now we need to parse this json format using the variable name from the json format. For instance if we need content variable we can get it using

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray){

            setTextView(jsonArray);

        }
```

The onPostExecute method is a part of the Asynctask. If you want that please let me know.

```
setTextView(JSONArray jsonArray){
     for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
////////////////here you are iterating through all the arrays in json file.
           try{
                json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                cont = json.getString("content");/////this brings the text in content variable to variable cont.

       }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Now you use the cont variable and assign it to the text view. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you help me a little what Asynctask is and the implementation of it :)

Comment: But the case is, the code above does not return any data or any string just like the output on the url

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I was not using Async task.

```
new GetTextTask().execute(new ApiConnector());
/////////////////call this when you want to parse the json page.
```

Here is the Async Task

```
 private class GetTextTask extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector,Long,JSONArray>{

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {
            return params[0].GetText();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray){

            setTextView(jsonArray);

        }

    }
```

You will also need Apiconnector class

```
public class ApiConnector {

    public JSONArray GetText(){

        String url = "your url for php";

        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

        try{

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

        if(httpEntity != null){
            try{
                String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                Log.e("Entity Response: ", entityResponse);
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return jsonArray;

    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey can you please mark the answer up, if you felt that was helpful.